# docker-compose up not recreate container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, containers

I create two containers, one is an oracle db and one is an apache tomcat.

I run both of them using the following docker compose:

```
version: '3.4'
services:
  tomcat:
     build: ./tomcat/.
     ports:
       - "8888:8080"
       - "59339:59339"
     depends_on:
       - oracle
     volumes:
       - ./tomcat/FILES:/usr/test/FILES
       - ./ROOT.war:/opt/tomcat/webapps/ROOT.war
     expose:
       - "8888"
       - "59339"
   oracle:
     build: ./database/.
     ports:
       - "49161:1521"
     environment:
       - ORACLE_ALLOW_REMOTE=true
     expose:
       - "49161"
```

I use the command *docker-compose up* that in according with the documentation it must be recreate the container.

But in reality it start only the old containers (same containers ID) with the state of the containers when it was stoped, this is a problem because I use it for testing and I want to start from a clean situation (ROOT.war must be deployed every time i run the command).

It is normal or I miss something.

**I'm using docker for windows 18.06.1-ce and Compose 1.22.0**

**UPDATE**

So is not true that *up* recreate container but do it only if something changed?

I also see `docker-compose down` that remove the container and force `up` to recreate them, is the right approch? 
The things that I not uderstand is why the status of the container was saved every time i stoped it (file *app.pid* create by tomcat still present after a simple *up* without a previous *down*)

Answer (score 2):

`docker-compose` starts and stops containers, if you want to recreate them every time you have to pass the `--force-recreate` flag as per the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/up/).

Answer (score 2):

`--force-recreate` will recreate the contianers

[From Docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/up/)

> --force-recreate => Recreate containers even if their configuration and image haven't
>   changed.

```
docker-compose up -d --force-recreate
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is as expected.

Sounds like you want to do a [restart](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/restart/):

```
docker-compose restart
```

or to force a rebuild:

```
docker-compose --build start
```